# When customizing the management server port, how is this implemented?

Tags: spring-boot

When reading through the spring boot documentation (http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-customizing-management-server-port), I see that you can customize the port on which actuator is running.  If I am using embedded tomcat, how is this implemented?  Is this creating another Connector or is it starting up a different instance of tomcat all together?  If it is tomcat, do we have any idea how much more memory this takes?

-Joshua

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It starts a separate embedded instance of Tomcat. The `/metrics` endpoint of Spring Boot's Actuator or a tool like JConsole will give you some insight into the heap usage.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer Andy.  For clarification, if I were to configure boot's embedded tomcat instance to use SSL for my app, are those settings carried over to the management instance?server.port = 8443
server.ssl.key-store = classpath:keystore.jks
server.ssl.key-store-password = secret
server.ssl.key-password = another-secret

Comment: Editing timed out...  I am looking to understand if I am using SSL only for the main part of my application, does the management port use SSL too or is it just regular http?

Comment: Other than the port, address, and context path, the management server uses the same server.* configuration: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.2.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-actuator/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/EndpointWebMvcChildContextConfiguration.java#L103