# Spring Boot Actuator port when deployed to external Tomcat container

Tags: tomcat, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot application that is deployed to an external Tomcat container (not using the embedded container), and am trying to get the actuator set up. The problem is that the `management.port` in `application.properties` does not seem to be honored by Tomcat. When I run Spring Boot with embedded Tomcat it works just fine.

For example, having the following set in `application.properties`:

`management.port=9010`

**Working endpoints for embedded container**

- `http://localhost:9010/health`

**Non-working endpoints for external container** running on port `8080`

- `http://localhost:9010/health`
- `http://localhost:8080/health`
- `http://localhost:9010/<appName>/health`
- `http://localhost:8080/<appName>/health`

Is there a special configuration I need in the Tomcat container to expose a Spring Boot actuator end point?

I've tried setting an environment variable of `MANAGEMENT_PORT`. Most (almost all) of the documentation available is using the embedded Tomcat, so tracking down this issue has proved to be challenging.

The third comment on this answer provided some possible insight: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28689853/2601060, which points to a GitHub file indicating that if the management port is not set, it will be the same as the server port.

Comment: The link you posted has an answer explaining that a separate instance is used for the actuator when using the embedded tomcat. Presumably that won't work when deploying to an external tomcat. There may be a way to achieve what you want to do, but it'll have to be in your external tomcat configuration, the properties for the embedded tomcat won't work.

Comment: @ci_ thanks for the response - are you aware of any way to configure that in the external tomcat?

Comment: Unfortunately not, or I would have posted an answer. I just commented to point you in the right direction. We use a separate context path for the actuators here, not a separate port.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We cannot specify an additional port with an external Tomcat container. 
Here is why : https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/552

The only way is to extend the endpoints using a context path, say "/management" and apply security on it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if your application.properties is having property called 
"management.port: 9001" and "server.port: 9000". Then your application end-points will deploy on port 9000 and actuator end-points will deployed on port 9001.

So its up to us. We can mention both properties with same port, application will works correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue in my local environement ,

- I fixed it by **changing the tomcat , (reinstalling a new one ),**
- also by **changing the default port in > \apache-tomcat-9.0.52\conf\serve.xml** to 8082
  -and then you can access to yout actuator link : localhost:8082/yourwarName/actuator/health

> :) hope it helps someone one day..

Answer (score 0):

What Java version are you running Tomcat7 under?

**N.B. This is all speculation - I haven't been able to verify this yet**

If it's `Java6` (and I'm guessing it is because I'm getting a similar issue), I suspect it's related to the following message:

> INFO: JSR 356 WebSocket (Java WebSocket 1.1) support is not available
>   when running on Java 6. To suppress this message, run Tomcat on Java
>   7, remove the WebSocket JARs from $CATALINA_HOME/lib or add the
>   WebSocket JARs to the tomcat.util.scan.DefaultJarScanner.jarsToSkip
>   property in $CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.properties. Note that the
>   deprecated Tomcat 7 WebSocket API will be available.

I can only hazard a guess, that Spring Boot use's [JSR356](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=356) to tell the Web App Container to "in addition to listening to the default port for the main app, also listen on port `X` for actuator endpoints"... and this isn't available running under `Java6`... I'm probably wrong.

If anyone could confirm/deny this behaviour, I'll update this response.

After setting Tomcat to use `Java8`, and removing the socket jars (`tomcat7-websocket.jar` & `websocket-api.jar` jars), I get the [following message from Spring](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-actuator/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration.java#L158-160):

> o.s.b.a.a.EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration : Could not start embedded management container on different port (management endpoints are still available through JMX)

In the meantime, @DecipherX's workaround (i.e. don't set `management.port=9010`) will expose your actuator endpoints through the default port.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the `management.server.port` from your configuration, the actuator will be deployed under the servlet context path in external Tomcat.

`http://<--domain-->/<--servlet-context-->/actuator/health`

> Unless the management port has been configured to expose endpoints by using a different HTTP port, management.endpoints.web.base-path is relative to server.servlet.context-path (Servlet web applications) or spring.webflux.base-path (reactive web applications). If management.server.port is configured, management.endpoints.web.base-path is relative to management.server.base-path.