# Spring Boot Server using HTTPS, Management Server only HTTP?

Tags: spring-boot

Based on an answer from @andy-wilkinson to a past Spring Boot [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28686229/when-customizing-the-management-server-port-how-is-this-implemented), it appears that with the exception of a couple parameters (port for example), the management server leverages the same configuration as the regular servlet container.

I would like to configure the main Spring Boot server to use HTTPS (for the application/service it is serving) and to use just HTTP for the actuator endpoints.  Has anyone done this?  Is this even possible?

-Joshua

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible at the moment. Please [open an issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/new) if it's an enhancement that you'd like to see.

Comment: Thanks, opened issue:   https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/3509